# Glossaries package and pagenumbering

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries, acronyms

I am using the `glossaries` package to maintain an Acronyms list and a Glossary.

My problem is that the Acronyms list is too big. Currently it is occupying 2 pages.

The first page is numbered as `vi`, which is how I want it. However, the second page is numbered as `1`, which is incorrect. It should be `vii`. Can someone help me?

This is how my master file looks like:

```
\begin{document}

\input{glossary} % The Glossary and Acronym entries.

\pagenumbering{alph}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\maketitle

\input{abstract}
\input{acknowledgments}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % Acronym list

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

% Document body

\printglossary[title={Index of Terms},toctitle={Index of Terms}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's good that you mark your code block. It's even better if you indent by just 4 spaces, not 8. (In some cases, you do want further indentation for clarity, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: Ok. So that was why you editted my post. The indentation I used is the one I normally use. Thought everyone liked it like that. Didn't I use code block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess you need a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`, depending on what you want and your documentclass, right after the `\printglossary`. Then your counter reset would not be executed until the next regular page.

That's assuming you mean the first glossary, since I can't test your code.